# Upgrading consumers from zk based offset storage to kafka based storage

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

I am using Golang and Sarama client. Kafka version is 0.9 which I plan to upgrade.

I am planning to upgrade sarama clients to latest version and use sarama-cluster instead of wvanbergen/kafka. I see that offset will be committed to kafka now.

On Apache Kafka page it says that for doing migration from zk based storage to kafka you need to do following:
Set offsets.storage=kafka and dual.commit.enabled=true in your consumer config.

There is no such property in wvanbergen/kafka library and they don't have plans to add it too.

Has anyone performed a similar upgrade from wvanbergen/kafka to sarama-cluster without the dual.commit.enabled settings on a production system? How did you migrate offsets from zk to kafka?

Comment: where is that _sarama-cluster_ client ?

Comment: For Kafka-based tracking (Kafka 0.9 and later), use https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster. For Zookeeper-based tracking (Kafka 0.8.2 and earlier), use https://github.com/wvanbergen/kafka. Is this what you are asking?